# Set PYTHONPATH, when virtualenv is activated

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

This moment, I am using `pyenv` + `venv` to manage `Python` versions and specific libraries. My project layout looks like this:

1. dir1

   - subdir11
   - subdir12
   - subdir13
2. dir2

   - subdir21
   - subdir22
   - subdir23

My goal is, once `venv` is activated `dir1` and `dir2` to be inside `sys.path`. Basically, I solve this task but I really do not like solution. I added custom `PYTHONPATH` inside `venv` under `bin/activate` file and everything works fine. This is not so flexible from deployment point of view. Does `venv` provide some `hooks` for this ? For example: set customer `environment variables` once `venv` is activated or run some function or something like this. I do not like idea, to modify `bin/activate` file on every machine.
P.S I know about packaging stuff and `setuptools`, but for this project I can not use it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility (which is usually what I use and avoids going into you venv source code) :

Create an `activate.sh` script where you export path to your modules AND activate venv ie :

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)
```

then you can just do `source activate.sh` instead of `source venv/bin/activate` and you will have both actions at once.

Comment: Yes, but it means `venv` does not provide some kind of `hooks`. Anyway, thanks for answer Luis. I just can vote up your answer.